# Using a .ttf in StyleConstants.setFontFamily

Tags: java, fonts, jtextpane

So I'm trying to use an apple II font in a project, but I'm having trouble figuring it out.

I can get it working as a Font object just fine, but StyleConstants.setFontFamily uses the params (MutableAttributeSet, String). How would I go about turning this .ttf into something that setFontFamily can work with?

```
public class PageLayout implements ActionListener
{  
  ....
  static Font appleII = new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 40); 
  ....
  public static void createAIIFont()
  {
    try
    {
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("PrintChar21.ttf"))
      Font base = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fis);
      appleII = base.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 24);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void setText(String text)
  {
    SimpleAttributeSet attribs = new SimpleAttributeSet();  
    StyleConstants.setFontFamily(attribs, "//This is where the issue is");
    int len = pane.getDocument().getLength();
    pane.setCaretPosition(len);
    pane.setParagraphAttributes(attribs,true);
    pane.replaceSelection(text);
  }
}
```

Comment: question posting tip: when you add your code, replace tabs with two spaces, because it lets people read more code without needing to scroll. And remove superfluous newlines, for the same reason. The less people need to scroll, the easier it is for them to immediately see what you're asking, and the less tempted they are to move on to a next question instead of spending time scrolling through your code.

Comment: What are you trying to set the font family attribute for? Looking at the method signature, you're doing it right, so what happens if you use a legal font family string? (like `abcdefghij`)

Comment: I might just be understanding this poorly, but if I set it to something like serif it'll change the font to serif. It doesn't work if I set it to appleII or PrintChar21, though.

Comment: A font family is not the same as a font name. That said, looking at the API here, these functions make no sense, what are you trying to actually do with this code?

Comment: I'm pulling text from a .txt, using setText (I excluded the other lines) to change the font size, color, and alignment, then displaying it in a JTextPane with pane.replaceSelection. I appreciate the help btw.

Comment: I got it to work by using StyleConstants.setFontFamily(attribs, appleII.getFamily()); while also having pane.setFont(appleII); in another method. Without either of these strings it doesn't work, but with both it does. Any idea why that is?

Comment: hm, I can't say that makes a lot of sense to me, sorry.